# Google sheets app script onEdit setting formula when cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup a sheet where people can write their work details every month that involves a lot of lookups but needs to allow people to add their own value if they need to. What I have got so far is:

```
function onEdit(e)

{
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = ssA.getSheetByName("Completed") 
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(5,6,lastRow,1);
  var data = range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {  
    if(!data[i][0])//If true then it's blank
    {
      data[i][0]="=IFERROR(INDEX('Client lookup sheet'!C[-1]:C[-1],MATCH(R[0]C[-4],'Client lookup sheet'!C[-5]:C[-5],false)),\"\")"
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
```

The sheet is setup so that when a client's name is entered, the next column will be used to lookup a corresponding location for that client. The code above is used so when the user accidentally deletes the formula in the locations column, the formula can be reset using the onEdit function.

The issue I'm having is that even though the code works fine for setting blank cells to have the formula, it also has the unwanted behavior of setting the lookup values to raw values so if say Jay is selected as the client, the location would be filled as Sydney NSW based on the lookup list but the setValues forces the cell to become Sydney NSW rather than retain the lookup formula.

Is there a way to check if the cells in the column has a formula and prevent it from being set as values if a formula is already there?

Thanks! and sorry for the long winded question

Comment: [Check if the cell has a formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula()). Based on this you can set an if statement.

Comment: How do I go about doing that for all the cells in data[i][0]? I get an error TypeError: Cannot find function when I try something like  {if(data[i][0].getFormulasR1C1()=="") to try and check if there is a formula in the cells

Comment: Right now you're acquiring all values. With values you cannot do anything else than checking the value. The formula that I linked requires a range. Take a look at the example that's provided in the reference guide.